# Field not populating in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, administration

Because of an external tools dependency, I'm having to add the "Full Name" of a user to the Account record, despite there being a lookup field on the Account as well.

We've hit the 15-unique object references threshold on formula fields on the SF Account object, so I am creating a text field "Growth Manager Full Name" and using a Flow to populate that field whenever the "Growth Manager" lookup field is changed.

The trigger logic is working fine. The problem is that, although the action step to populate Growth Manager Full Name with the value of $Record > Growth Manager > Full Name is successfully running, it's coming back null.

[image]
[image]
[image]

But the user I'm testing with (myself) has a Full Name value (see below).  Why would this be coming back "Null" in the flow?

[image]

Comment: are you testing as if this is a new record rather than a record being updated?